# Javascript - Return object's values on separate lines in single string

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have the following object:

```
const parent = {
   "name": "John",
   "age": 35,
   "relationship": "married"
}
```

I would like to obtain all the values of the `parent` properties on separate lines in a single string such as:

```
John
35
married
```

Time-efficiency is key to me since I will be working with thousands of objects with each having more than 100 000 properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
Object.values(parent).join("\n");
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. However, if the `parent` object had an empty property (i.e. `"children" = ""`) it would just display as an empty line in the result string. Is there a way of adding a default value to it inside the string? Say, `-99` instead of just `\n`?

Comment: `Object.values(parent).map(function(e){return e.length == 0 ? '-99' : e}).join("\n");` but will loose performance